# How can I integrate custom fields in CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to integrate custom fields in the CiviCRM. If yes how can Integrate the fields in the CRM? as I am having a [Bulk SMS service](https://msg91.com) website I want to add some custom fields in the CRM

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Administer" menu there is a "Customize Data and Screens" option. You can add custom fields there.

In future I recommend searching through the menu before posting :)